# Php-mysql injection

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db_server = "localhost";
$db_name = "2";
$db_user = "root";
$db_passwd = "";

$connection = mysql_connect($db_server,$db_user,$db_passwd);
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die("Couldn't Select Database");

if($_POST['text']){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id='".  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<span>".$row['id']."</span>";
    }
}
?>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Anyway to inject the mysql on this kind of structure?
The database on with 1 Table 1 column with name id, just simple store "abc,bca,cab".
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). If you're worrying about vulnerabilities you might as well stay away from `mysql_*` altogether. It's actually encouraged.

Comment: I know using mysqli or pdo will be more security i guess so, but actually i think mysql structure more easier to write so i try on mysql to do server connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no.

But mysql_real_escape_string **isn't the only thing** that protects you here.

See :

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']); // $_POST['text'] == "1 OR 1=1"
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = $text");
```

You're not protected here, and an injection was made. So your quotes are protecting you against this here. You could also type cast (int) instead since it's an id.

As a side note, you shouldn't use mysql, but [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) instead.

With [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) you can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) that'll protect you against any of this, as it will perform the query with the dynamic part treated as a **string** at all time.

Comment: So its depend on the way i write that can affect the security of my query?Actually i saw a lots of forum suggest not using mysql on php statement , so i try to prove something that mysql actually still can prevent the inject like the structure i wrote. By the way i still know mysqli and PDO is the best way to do on server-side query.I still agree on you that prepared statements on mysqli / PDO is more suitable.

Comment: Yes of course, the way you write will affect the security of the query. You could actually have a whole secure application with mysql only. But that implies you doing same things again and again, and that means you only need to forget to "secure" your query manually **once** to be exploited. Any scanner will find this kind of breach in a breeze.

Comment: Using PDO instead of mysqli might be (or pretty much is) even better idea.

Comment: PDO is only a wrapper that uses mysqli in this case. So it doesn't matter.